# How to add pipe asynch to observable that is not in the html template in Angular?

Tags: angular

I have this Angular code:

```
<mat-table [dataSource]="myData">

<ng-container matColumnDef="abc">
   <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Abc</mat-header-cell>
   <mat-cell *matCellDef="let myData" [style.color]="getColor(myData.myVal)">{{ myData?.myVal }}</mat-cell>
</ng-container>

</mat-table>
```

.ts

```
  @Input() myData: MyData[] = [];

  standardColor:string = '';
  warningColor:string = '';

  constructor(
    ...
  ) {   
    this.getSettings();
  }
  
  
  getSettings(){
   this.settings$ = this.settingsService.getSettings()
      .pipe(shareReplay(),
        catchError(error => {
          this.onError();
          return of({} as setting);
        })
      );

      this.settings$.subscribe(result => { 
        this.standardColor = result.standardColor;
        this.warningColor = result.warningColor;
      });
  } 
  
  
  getColor(myVal: number){
    if(myVal > 0){
      return this.standardColor;
    } else {
      return this.warningColor;
    } 

  }
```

When getColor is executed in mat-cell, it is returning empty string.

Instead, it should return the value that comes from the observable (line `this.standardColor = result.standardColor;`).

That is because the this.settings$ observable is asynchronous and is executing after the html template.

Understand this is usually solved by adding pipe async ( | asynch ) to the template.

But in this case it is a different observable (settings$), not the datasource in the template binding (myData).

Comment: you can also use the async pipe here `<mat-cell *matCellDef="let myData" [style.color]=" (settings$ | async).myColor">{{ myData?.myVal }}</mat-cell>`

Comment: you can just call `this.cdr.detectChanges` after   `this.myColor = result.myColor;`

Assuming you're using onpush strat

Comment: @oksd Your solution works the way you proposed, but in my case there's one additional thing. In reality I need to pass a parameter to define the color. I didn't put that here in the question for simplicity, but the actual code looks more like this: [style.color]="getColor(myData.myVal)". Then, in getColor I check myVal and return a different color depending on it. How can I do that using the pipe async like you suggested?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you could convert getSettings() to an observable method and then wait for it to return the settings before showing your data:

```
myWarningColor: string = '';
myStandarColor: string = '';
settings$ = this.getSettings();

getSettings(): Observable<boolean> {
  return this.settingsService.getSettings().pipe(
    shareReplay(),
    catchError((error) => {
      return of({} as any);
    }),
    tap((result) => {
      this.myWarningColor = result.warningColor;
      this.myStandarColor = result.standardColor;
    }),
    switchMap(() => of(true))
  );
}
```

Then in the template:

```
    <div *ngIf="settings$ | async">
      <div *ngFor="let item of myData">
        <span [style.color]="this.getColor(item.myVal)">{{ item.myVal }}</span>
        <span [style.color]="this.getColor(item.myVal)">COLOR</span>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Of course, that means that you must wait for the settings method to return before showing any data, but on the other hand, you would be displaying the wrong color coding if you don't have the settings.

Check this working example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-7fn78y?file=src%2Fmain.ts

Comment: Great. This solved my problem. The solution is this part of your code: ```<div *ngIf="settings$ | async">```. I did it a little bit differently using ng-container. So it became ```<ng-container *ngIf="settings$ | async"><mat-table [dataSource]="myData">...</mat-table></ng-container>```. All the rest remained the same. Thanks!